# What's the best way to upload local file to instance using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In this case, I am trying to copy the .pem file to the bastion host. But if I wanted to simply copy a file on my local machine to the instance, what's the best way to achieve this?

In terraform, this can be done with a  provisioner file. Is there something similar for cloudformation>

I have tried to use the "file" for example:

```
"Metadata":{
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
"files" : {
```

but I am unsure how to use this to copy file.
Do you have suggestions?

Comment: I think the easiest way is store your key into s3 bucket,  and access via cloudformation

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/authenticated-file-downloads-with-cloudformation/